# Remove Output Cache for one subdomain in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have different subdomains:
e.g.:

- subdomain1.domain.com/Home/Index
- subdomain2.domain.com/Home/Index

and i use OutputCache for chaching my Pages.
It looks like it:

```
[OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 1800, VaryByHeader = "Host")]
public ActionResult Index()
{               
    ClubSiteHomeModel model = new ClubSiteHomeModel(VClub);
    return View(model);                
}
```

I would like to remove cached data only for one subdomain. What should I do?

Comment: I believe this can be achieved by using VaryByCustom="Host", and you would need to override "GetVaryByCustomString" in Global.asax and write your logic to include/ exclude OutputCache based on subdomain.

Comment: I am looking for server localisation where cached sites are saved. Till now i haven't find it. Maybe if i was able to do it it would be easier.